# derive formula for the height error in the cone filling with ice cream

Tags: calculus

Your niece is visiting you, and you are serving her ice cream in a conical glass (conical shape whose bottom is the tip of the cone). *The diameter of the opening is 3 inches*, and *the cone is 6 inches tall*. You plan to fill the cone part way to a height $h$. Your niece requires that you smooth the ice cream so that it lies perfectly flat. Your niece is very persnickety, and requires that you fill the dish to a height $h_0=3$in. She allows for a margin of error $|Δh|≤0.01$. In principle it is possible to satisfy her wishes because the cone has a height of 6 in. Unfortunately, there are no markings on the cone. However, she plans to measure the height using a calibrated laser after you serve it. Your only tool is a collection of scoops that are capable of measuring volumes within an error of $|ΔV|≤0.1$.

Find the exact volume $V_0$ in terms of π of ice cream that you need to serve your niece. Then derive an approximate formula for the height error $Δh$ in terms of the volume error $ΔV$.
$$V=\pi r^2\frac h3$$
$$V_0=\pi r^2\frac {h_0}{3}$$, so $V_0= \frac {9}{16} \pi$, since $r$ in this cone is $\frac h4$

is it correct? and how to derive the approximate formula?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. To derive the approximate formula, calculate $\Delta V$ in the following formula
$$ V_0 + \Delta V = \pi \left(\frac{h_0+\Delta h}{4}\right)^2 \frac{h_0+\Delta h}{3} $$
in terms of $\Delta h$.
If you need more help, just leave a comment.

Comment: I got that $Δh=(27+\frac {48ΔV}{\pi} )^\frac 13$. There was a hint in my problem that "You don't use delta V symbolically -- you substitute the actual numeric value for delta V that was provided in the problem statement." but when I put 0.1 instead of $ΔV$, answer is still wrong. and if I calculate $ΔV=V-V_0$ and get $3\frac {15}{16} \pi$ it is wrong again. where is my mistake?

Comment: @Sarah You forgot to subtract h to get Δh,actual formula h+Δh=(27+48ΔV/π)^1/3